# how to calculate sleep duration using sleep and wake times

Tags: r

I have a data set with sleep time and wake up time and was looking for a way to calculate sleep duration.
I tried to do the difference in values but it didn't work because sleep time is sometimes coded as "200", "2330" or "2445".

for example

```
   sleeptime    wakeuptime
1   200       800
2   2330      730
3   2400      700
4   2200      1100
5   100       1000
6   2445      900
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A time class (e.g. [hms](https://hms.tidyverse.org/)) would make this easier. Or stick with POSIXct and difftime. [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) may also be helpful, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach to consider.

You can write a function that converts/formats your numeric times to strings and calculates the number of minutes.

Then, since the times cross midnight, you can use an `ifelse` statement to determine the time difference (in minutes).

```
mins_since_MN <- function(x) {
  str_time <- sprintf("%04.0f", x)
  (as.numeric(substring(str_time, 1, 2)) * 60) + as.numeric(substring(str_time, 3, 4)) 
}

df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, mins_since_MN))

with(df2, ifelse(sleeptime > wakeuptime, wakeuptime - sleeptime + (60 * 24), wakeuptime - sleeptime))
[1] 360 480 420 780 540 495
```

**Data**

```
df = data.frame(
  sleeptime = c(200, 2330, 2400, 2200, 100, 2445),
  wakeuptime = c(800, 730, 700, 1100, 1000, 900)
)
```

Comment: that was very helpful, thanks. I did a small change to get the "sleepduration" as a list,  
 `df2$sleepduration<- with(df2, ifelse(sleeptime > wakeuptime, wakeuptime - sleeptime + (60 * 24), wakeuptime - sleeptime))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do:

```
library(lubridate)

# sample df
df = data.frame(sleeptime = c(200, 2330, 2400, 2200, 100, 2445),
                wakeuptime = c(800, 730, 700, 1100, 1000, 900))

# convert columns to seconds
df = do.call(data.frame, lapply(df, lubridate::seconds))

# get time diff
df$diff <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[2] - x[1])
```